# Android Architecture Components how to achieve two-way bindings for objects with ViewModel

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

Here is a very basic view model as such

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val text = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val person = MutableLiveData<Person>()
}
```

I'm trying to achieve two way binding as shown below

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={viewModel.text}"/>
```

This works as expected but when it comes to binding the object:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={viewModel.person.name}"/>
```

I'm getting an error:
The expression viewModelPersonGetValue.getName() cannot be inverted: Two-way binding cannot resolve a setter for java.lang.String property 'name'

It appears that I am missing something, any ideas?

(I am using Android Studio 3.2 canary 1)

Comment: i tried that too: it seems that `@=` is not ready yet to work with `LiveData` but I can't be 100% sure

Comment: name property has a setter?  Can you show the Person class?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for your problem? Currently I am trying to combine Databinding with LiveData in my own project.

Comment: My problem was that i had not installed the 3.1 version of Android Studio. After installing it and adding getters and setters for the designated property to my `ViewModel` i could use `MutableLiveData`. Here are two helpful links which may help you. http://gradlewhy.ghost.io/binding-models-from-livedata-to-android-views/ https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-livedata-with-data-binding-7bf85871bbd8

Comment: > This works properly in the new version of Android Studio, which supports binding to LiveData objects properly. This has been answered in a related question: [EditText LiveData Two-way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49723950/edittext-livedata-two-way-binding/49725818#49725818)

Comment: Like Alan said, make sure that `name` has a setter. In Kotlin this means declaring the property as `var` (not `val`).

Answer (score 3):

This should work on Android Studio 3.1 and above as long as you don't forget to include

```
val binding: ActivityMainBinding = ...
binding.viewModel = viewModel 
binding.setLifecycleOwner(this) // The editText won't update without this
```

Comment: Very important to set the `viewModel` property as well. Without that it does not work, so **both properties are very important.**