# EditText LiveData Two-way binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Okay, so I have a `ViewModel` with a getter `getTitle()` that returns `MutableLiveData<String>`.

```
<EditText
    style="@style/Widget.EditText.FullWidth"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/label_title"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@={ viewModel.title }" />
```

This works fine at first: the `EditText` contains the value of the `MutableLiveData` when it first appears. However, if the value of this data is updated using `MutableLiveData.setValue()` (such as by another `EditText`, or from my code), then the value inside of the text box does not change. How do I fix this?

Comment: please share your viewmodel class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works properly in the [new version of Android Studio](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/04/android-studio-32-canary-9-now-available.html), which supports binding to `LiveData` objects properly.